# Creating multidimensional array with database values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the result of a MYSQL query as shown below:

```
    **category_id**  **category_name**  **main_category**
     1            Dancing        Hobbies
     2            Painting       Hobbies
     3            Hip Hop        Music
     4            Jazz           Music
```

I am using MVC framework and the query is as shown below:

```
$db->select(array("a"=>"nesote_matrimony_userinterest","b"=>"nesote_matrimony_category","c"=>"nesote_matrimony_category"));
        $db->fields("a.category_id,b.category_name,b.parent_id,c.category_name,c.parent_id");
        $db->where("a.category_id=b.id and a.user_id=? and c.parent_id=0 and c.id=b.parent_id",$id);
        $db->order("c.category_name asc");

        $interestquery=$db->query();
```

I need the result of the query to be stored as an array like

```
 array[0][0]= Hobbies

 array[0][1]= Dancing,Painting

 array[1][0]= Music

 array [1][1]= Hip Hop, Jazz
```

So that I can display the resultant as

Hobbies :  Dancing,Painting

in the web page. How can I create an array in the above format, from the resultant query result using PHP ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check my answer ,it will do

Answer (score 0):

just use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Syntax:`array mysqli_fetch_assoc ( mysqli_result $result )`

if using PDO then checkout http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

for example :

you execute certain query:

like `$a=mysqli_query("your select query");`

now in order to get the result in the form of multidimensional array,you will be writing.

```
$aa= mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $a );
print_r($aa);//will print the content of the array

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aa)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["category_name"], $row["main_category"]);
}
```

**you can insert the same into your database.

**NOTE:Dont use mysql_ as they are depracated.**

Comment: I am using PHP- MySQL

Comment: perfect :) see my updated answer :)and if any doubt please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

SQL

```
SELECT 
    group_concat(category_name SEPARATOR ','), main_category
FROM
    test.test
GROUP BY main_category;
```

PHP

```
<?php

$host = '';
$dbname = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";
                dbname=" . $dbname . ";charset=utf8", 
                $user, $password, array(
                   PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE
                 ));
$sql = "SELECT 
    group_concat(category_name SEPARATOR ',')as category, main_category as main
FROM
    test.test
GROUP BY main_category;";

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bindColumn('category', $category);
$stmt->bindColumn('main', $main);

while ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
    $list[$main] = $category;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
// this the array from mysql 
$array= array(array('id'=>1,'name'=>'dancing', 'main'=>'hobbies'),    array('id'=>2,'name'=>'paint', 'main'=>'hobbies'), array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'hip    hop','main'=>'music'));


$data= array();
 foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
$data[$value['main']][] = $value['name']; 
}

 // then 
$all = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach($data as $main=>$sub) {
  $all[$counter][0] = $main;
  $all[$counter][1] = implode(',', $sub);
  $counter++;
}
die(print_r($all));
```